# HTML5 Application | offline

Tags: ipad, caching, safari

We have a HTML5 application where we cache pages using offline manifest. The pages are working offline for all browsers except for iPad Safari. We are able to cache the pages on iPhone Safari too. We also found that the page works offline when the browser is reopened. Could you please let us know how to cache pages on Safari browser for iPad?